# PostgreSQL UUID date type

Tags: python, postgresql, uuid

I'm building a platform with a PostgreSQL database (first time) but I've experience with Oracle and MySQL databases for a few years now.

My question is about the UUID data type in Postgres.
I am using an UUIDv4 uuid to indentify a record in multiple tables, so the request to /users/2df2ab0c-bf4c-4eb5-9119-c37aa6c6b172 will respond with the user that has that UUID. I also have an auto increment ID field for indexing.

My query is just a `select` with a `where` clause on `UUID`. But when the user enters an invalid UUID like this `2df2ab0c-bf4c-4eb5-9119-c37aa6c6b17` (without the last `2`) then the database responds with this error: `Invalid input syntax for UUID`.

I was wondering why it returned this because when you `select` on a `integer`-type with a `string`-type it does work.

Now I need to set a middleware/check on each route that has an `UUID`-type parameter in it because otherwise the server would crash.

Btw I'm using Flask 0.12 (Python) and PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UUID as defined by RFC 4122, ISO/IEC 9834-8:2005... is a 128-bit quantity ... written as a sequence of lower-case hexadecimal digits... for a total of 32 digits representing the 128 bits. (Postgresql Docs)

There is no conversion from a 31 hex digits text to a 128-bit UUID (sorry). You have some options:

1. Convert to ::text on your query (not really recommended, because you'd be converting every row, every time).

   ```
   SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_uuid::TEXT = 'invalid uid';
   ```
2. Don't store it as a UUID type. If you don't want / need UUID semantics, store it as a varchar.
3. Check your customer input. (My recommendation). Conceptually, this is no different from asking for someone's age and getting 'ABC' as the response.

Postgres allows upper/lower case, and is flexible about use of hyphens, so a pre-check is simply strip the hyphens, lowercase, count `[0-9[a-f]` & if == 32, you have a workable UUID. Otherwise, rather than telling your user "not found", you can tell them, "not a UUID", which is probably more user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks. I also thought that checking the uuid was the best and most user-friendly option

Answer (score 0):

The database is throwing an error because you're trying to match in a UUID-type column with a query that *doesn't contain a valid UUID*.  This doesn't happen with integer or string queries because leaving off the last character of those *does* result in a valid integer or string, just not the one you probably intended.

You can either prevent passing invalid UUIDs to the database by validating your input (which you should be doing anyway for other reasons) or somehow trap on this error.  Either way, you'll need to present a human-readable error message back to the user.

Also consider whether users should be typing in URLs with UUIDs in the first place, which isn't very user-friendly; if they're just clicking links rather than typing them, as usually happens, then how did that error even happen?  There's a good chance that it's an attack of some sort, and you should respond accordingly.